# LastModifiedFileListFilter for Sftp inbound adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am trying to implement `LastModifiedFileListFilter` as it looks like there is no similar filter for spring-integration-sftp yet for 5.3.2 release, I tried to copy the `LastModifiedFileListFilter` from spring-integration-file but the discard callback isn't working. Here is my implementation:

```
@Slf4j
@Data
public class LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter implements DiscardAwareFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> {

  private static final long ONE_SECOND = 1000;

  private static final long DEFAULT_AGE = 30;

  private volatile long age = DEFAULT_AGE;

  @Nullable
  private Consumer<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> discardCallback;

  public LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter(final long age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  @Override
  public List<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> filterFiles(final ChannelSftp.LsEntry[] files) {

    final List<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = new ArrayList<>();
    final long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / ONE_SECOND;

    for (final ChannelSftp.LsEntry file : files) {

      if (this.fileIsAged(file, now)) {
        log.info("File [{}] is aged...", file.getFilename());

        list.add(file);
      } else if (this.discardCallback != null) {
        log.info("File [{}] is still being uploaded...", file.getFilename());
        this.discardCallback.accept(file);
      }
    }
    return list;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean accept(final ChannelSftp.LsEntry file) {
    if (this.fileIsAged(file, System.currentTimeMillis() / ONE_SECOND)) {
      return true;
    }
    else if (this.discardCallback != null) {
      this.discardCallback.accept(file);
    }
    return false;
  }

  private boolean fileIsAged(final ChannelSftp.LsEntry file, final long now) {
    return file.getAttrs().getMTime() + this.age <= now;
  }

  @Override
  public void addDiscardCallback(@Nullable final Consumer<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> discardCallbackToSet) {
    this.discardCallback = discardCallbackToSet;
  }
}
```

The filter is able to correctly identify the age of file and discards it but that file is not retried which I believe is part of discard callback.
I guess my question is how to set discard callback to keep retrying the discarded file until files `ages`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not retried which I believe is part of discard callback.

I wonder what makes you think that way...

The fact that `FileReadingMessageSource` with its `WatchService` option has the logic like this:

```
if (filter instanceof DiscardAwareFileListFilter) {
            ((DiscardAwareFileListFilter<File>) filter).addDiscardCallback(this.filesToPoll::add);
        }
```

doesn't mean that SFTP implementation is similar.

The retry is there anyway: on the next poll not accepted file will be checked again.

You probably don't show other filters you use, and your file is filtered out before this `LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter`, e.g. with the `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`. You need to consider to have your "last-modified" as a first one in the chain.

If you are not going to support discard callback from the outside, you probably don't need to implement that `DiscardAwareFileListFilter` at all.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction. Yes it was indeed the other filters that were causing the issue. I shuffled the sequence of filters and it worked as expected. Also as you suggested I was not using any outside discard callback so implemented `FileListFilter` instead. Thanks again !!